# Как отключить jquery в joomla 2.5?

Tags: jquery, joomla

Как убрать, чтобы его не было в head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в файл index.php вашего шаблона после defined ('_JEXEC') or die, добавить

```
unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
```